# Generic way to convert one model to another model

Tags: c#, generics, model-view-controller, model

i have two model ***User*** and ***UserModelDto*** both have some property in common and from client side i got ***UserModelDto*** model and i want to convert it into ***User*** for inserting into database(i am using entity framework). And when it convert All property value of ***UserModelDto*** i want to copy into ***User*** whether that property contain value or not if not Contain then appropriate value manually(like null) assigned to it.i want it in generic way. 
Model  ***User*** is look like

```
 public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.UserRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ManagerId { get; set; }
    public byte AuthenticationType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> RememberMe { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsOnVacation { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsManager { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public int LoginAttempts { get; set; }
    public bool ResetPassword { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastDealAssignedDateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

and Model ***UserModelDto*** look like....

```
public class UserModelDto
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public byte AuthenticationType { get; set; }
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool IsOnVacation { get; set; }
    public bool IsManager { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public int ManagerId { get; set; }
    public int PrimaryRoleid { get; set; }
}
```

**And What i tried is**

```
 public User ConvertToUserModel(UserModelDto userModel)
    {
        User convertedUser = new User();
        if (userModel!=null)
        {
            convertedUser.Id = userModel.UserId != null ? userModel.UserId : 0;
            convertedUser.AuthenticationType = userModel.AuthenticationType != null ? userModel.AuthenticationType : 0;
            convertedUser.EmailId = userModel.EmailId != null ? userModel.EmailId :null;
            convertedUser.FirstName = userModel.FirstName != null ? userModel.FirstName : null;
            convertedUser.LastName = userModel.LastName != null ? userModel.LastName : null;
            convertedUser.IsOnVacation = userModel.IsOnVacation != null ? userModel.IsOnVacation : false;
            convertedUser.IsActive = userModel.IsActive != null ? userModel.IsActive : false;
            convertedUser.IsManager = userModel.IsManager != null ? userModel.IsManager : false;
            convertedUser.ManagerId = userModel.ManagerId != null ? userModel.ManagerId :0;
            convertedUser.UserName = userModel.UserName != null ? userModel.UserName :null; 
        }
        return convertedUser;
    }
```

Comment: You could use conversion operators. Explicit or Implicit. You would put the logic in one of the files, and when you cast, the conversion code would run.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx

Comment: Tip: instead of `userModel.UserId != null ? userModel.UserId : 0`, you can use `userModel.GetValueOrDefault()`, which returns a `0`, `false` or `null` as required, when the real value is missing.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest you look at something like [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) which does exactly what you're asking for.  It allows you lots of configuration options, and I've used it for this exact use case many times.

Here's what you would literally do.

```
//Type on left is source type, type on right is destination
Mapper.CreateMap<UserModelDto, User>();

User user = Mapper.Map<User>(userDto);
```

To go the other way from `UserDto` to `User`, you would just create a new mapper with the types flipped, and follow the same pattern.

There's a [nice in depth video](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=155) that gives you more examples of what you can do with Automapper, but in this case the default configuration should work just fine.

Comment: Agreed here.  It will also encourage consistency through convention.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show how the mapping should be configured exactly to reach the OP's situation.

Comment: I don't think this will fully yield the same result. Notice how in the question he demonstrates rules like "if field is not null, use value, otherwise use false". I'm not sure but I believe AutoMapper would use `null` instead of `false`.

Answer (score 3):

I use a utility called AutoMapper:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/

This allows you to convert one object to another as simply as:

```
User mappedUser = AutoMapper.Map<User>(userModelDto);
```

This will automatically map properties of the same type and name, although special mapping rules can be defined in the configuration.